# typescript - how to export all includes default when you don't know about default existence

Tags: typescript, export, default

I have a file `foo.ts` I got from a user, which may or may not export default (`export default function(){}`). I know I can parse the file to find out, I prefer not to, for performance and simplicity reasons.

I need to create a file, "link file" that exports everything from this file "foo", including default and non-default.

In the JS world, it's easy: `module.exports = require('./foo');`  Now I can use this link file the same way I use foo.js file. they both export the same things.

In the TS world, however, if I do `export * from './foo'`, I only get the non-default. To get the default I have to add `export { default } from './foo';`.

The problem is that, as I stated earlier, I don't know whether `foo.ts` has a default export, so if my link file always has `export { default } from './foo';`, it'll throw an error when foo doesn't have default export.

So, my question is basically, what is the equivalent of `module.exports = require('./foo');` in TS.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I can do `export = something`, so the following solves my problem:

```
import * as foo from './foo';
export = foo;
```

the following works as well

```
import foo = require('./foo');
export = foo;
```